# Parsing a string To Obtain two values

Tags: c#, .net

What would be the simplest way of parsing this string I just want to get the two values out of it. I need to get the value after QueryParameter Parameter=\ and then the value from after \"$MPElement[Name='

Any help apreciated I did try the following code

```
string myString = listQueryParameter[0]._parameter.ToString();
string text= myString.Split(new [] {"QueryParameter Parameter="}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

But it still gave me everything after value along with it thanks.

```
<QueryParameter Parameter=\"TypeProjectionId\" Value=\"$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$\" xmlns=\"clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework\" />"
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on XML, but it looks like the tool for this job is XPath

Comment: I would use an xml parser.

Comment: Personally I would first wonder where this invalid XML comes from, why it is invalid, and how one can get valid XML instead. **Then** use an XML parser.

Comment: Or regex - but that can be a problem in itself.

Comment: I have done that to get to this point but I dont no how to get the element from the child. I just want to parse this string :-(

Comment: @Timwi its from Microsoft service centre manager its their own markup

Comment: @DavidBuckley: No, it’s not. They do not mangle XML in this way. My guess is that you looked at the string in the VS debugger and saw it with the backslashes added and then assumed that they are part of the string. They are not.

Comment: Ah Right @Timwi no when i copied it from the sql table for managmentpackview that is how it was formed its obv to escape it when stored in db is it not

Comment: I am not familiar with the SQL viewer you mention, but I can elaborate a bit on what Timwi means when he suggested that you were misled by the Visual Studio debugger. It is a typical problem - should they show you the data in a format that you can copy-and-paste into a C# string (good service for programmers), or should they show you the actual characters one-for-one? Visual Studio debugger provides both views, but the first, default, view is the programmer-oriented view where they add backslash characters as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input looks like XML, but isn’t really valid XML.

My recommendation is to investigate where this stuff comes from, and fix the source so that it will produce correct XML. My guess is that in actuality you already have valid XML, but you looked at the string in the VS debugger and saw it with the backslashes added and then assumed that they are part of the string. If this is the case, then rest assured that they are not.

For reference, valid XML might look like this:

```
<QueryParameter Parameter="TypeProjectionId" Value="$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$" xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework" />
```

In other words, it’s the same as yours but without the backslashes.

Now we can use `XElement.Parse` to turn this into a parsed value:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(myString);
```

If you feed the *invalid* XML to this, this will throw.

Now we want to look at the values of the two attributes `Parameter` and `Value`:

```
var parameter = xml.Attribute("Parameter").Value;
var value = xml.Attribute("Value").Value;
```

At this point, `value` contains the string `$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$`. You said you wanted the part after `Name=`, so let’s use a regular expression for that:

```
var match = Regex.Match(value, @"\bName='([^']*?)'");
if (!match.Success)
    throw new Exception("The Value attribute is not in a recognized format.");
var innerValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: its microsoft service center own form of xml